# How to optimize canvas or something else on site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, optimization

[Here is a site](http://silencer.website/alkor/), in it a canvas (airplane), which lags when scrolling, appear artifacts, and in different ways, depending on what you scroll - with the mouse wheel or scrollbar. If you comment out parallax or video at the beginning, nothing changes. During the scrolling of calls to the house does not happen. Lags either from behind the airplane script, or because of a clearRect. How can I optimize and get rid of artifacts? The code on the [codepen](https://codepen.io/SilencerWeb/pen/ayQbZb) (it works fine)

```
var scrolled;
  var positionsArr = [];
  var commonHeight = 0;
  var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
  var canvasB = document.querySelector('#canvasback');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var ctxB = canvasB.getContext('2d');
  var centerX, centerY, radius, pointsOffset, radiusRatio, centerXRatio,
    firstPoint, lastPoint, jet, blocksPosition, jetPositionY, jetTop, tabletOffset, headerHeight, canvasClearWidth;
  var wWidth, mediaMobile, mediaTablet, mediaDesktop1, mediaDesktop2, mediaDesktop3;

  jet = new Image();
  jet.src = 'http://silencer.website/alkor/images/jet.png';
  jet.onload = function () {
    adaptive();
  }

  $(window).on('resize', function () {
    adaptive();
  });

  function adaptive() {
    mediaMobile = mediaTablet = mediaDesktop1 = mediaDesktop2 = mediaDesktop3 = false;
    wWidth = $(window).width();

    // Параметры для дуги по умолчанию
    tabletOffset = 0;
    radiusRatio = .95;
    centerXRatio = 1.25;

    // Параметры для дуги на разных разрешениях (перезаписывают параметры по умолчанию)
    if (wWidth < 768) {
      mediaMobile = true;
    }
    if (wWidth >= 768 && wWidth < 1024) {
      mediaTablet = true;
      tabletOffset = 120;
    }
    if (wWidth >= 1024 && wWidth < 1280) {
      mediaDesktop1 = true;
      tabletOffset = -40;
      radiusRatio = 1.1;
      centerXRatio = 1.03;
    }
    if (wWidth >= 1280 && wWidth < 1440) {
      mediaDesktop2 = true;
      tabletOffset = -20;
    }
    if (wWidth >= 1440) {
      mediaDesktop3 = true;
      tabletOffset = -20;
    }

    if (!mediaMobile) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        doCanvas();
      }, 500);
    } else {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      $(window).off('scroll', onScroll);
    }
  }

  function doCanvas() {
    $(window).on('scroll', onScroll);

    var marginBottom = 120;
    commonHeight = 0;

    $('.history__item').each(function () {
      commonHeight = commonHeight + $(this).height() + marginBottom;
    });
    commonHeight = commonHeight - marginBottom;

    canvasWidth = $('.history').width() * .3;
    canvasHeight = $('.history__blocks').height();
    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;

    canvasB.width = canvas.width;
    canvasB.height = canvas.height;

    offsetLeft = $('.history__blocks')[0].offsetLeft;
    $('#canvas, #canvasback').css('marginLeft', -offsetLeft);

    radius = commonHeight * radiusRatio;
    centerX = -commonHeight / centerXRatio + offsetLeft + tabletOffset;
    centerY = commonHeight / 2;
    pointsOffset = 100;

    canvasClearWidth = centerX + radius + 110;

    blocksPosition = $('.history__blocks')[0].offsetTop;
    jetPositionY = $('.history')[0].offsetTop;
    headerHeight = $('.history__title').height();
    jetTop = $(window).height() / 2;

    jetOnScroll = jetTop - headerHeight - jetPositionY;

    positionsArr = [];

    lastIndex = $('.history__item').length - 1;
    darkened = $('.history__item');

    for (var i = 0; i < $('.history__item').length; i++) {
      var position = $('.history__item').eq(i)[0].offsetTop - blocksPosition + pointsOffset;
      positionsArr.push(position);

      if (i == 0) {
        firstPoint = position;
      }

      if (i == $('.history__item').length - 1) {
        lastPoint = position;
      }
    }

    draw();
    drawBackground();
    setTimeout(function () {
      if (mediaTablet) {
        jetPositionLine(firstPoint);
      } else {
        jetPosition(firstPoint);
      }

    }, 100);
  }

  function drawBackground() {
    if (mediaTablet) {
      drawLine();
    } else {
      drawArc();
    }
  }

  function draw(currentY) {
    for (var i = 0; i < positionsArr.length; i++) {
      addPoint(positionsArr[i], currentY, i);
    }
  }

  function drawArc() {
    var firstPointRad = Math.asin((centerY - firstPoint) / radius);
    var lastPointRad = Math.asin((centerY - lastPoint) / radius);

    ctxB.beginPath();
    ctxB.lineWidth = 3;
    ctxB.save();
    ctxB.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5, lastPointRad, true);
    ctxB.strokeStyle = '#99daf0';
    ctxB.setLineDash([8, 5]);
    ctxB.lineDashOffset = 1;
    ctxB.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
    ctxB.stroke();
    ctxB.restore();
  }

  function drawLine() {
    ctxB.beginPath();
    ctxB.lineWidth = 3;
    ctxB.save();
    ctxB.lineTo(tabletOffset, firstPoint);
    ctxB.lineTo(tabletOffset, lastPoint);
    ctxB.strokeStyle = '#99daf0';
    ctxB.setLineDash([8, 5]);
    ctxB.lineDashOffset = 1;
    ctxB.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
    ctxB.stroke();
    ctxB.restore();
  }

  function addPoint(y, currentY, i) {
    if (mediaTablet) {
      var currentX = tabletOffset;
    } else {
      var angle = Math.asin((centerY - y) / radius);
      var currentX = centerX + radius * (Math.cos(angle));
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(currentX, y, 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00a3da';
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    if (currentY + 10 >= y) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
      darkened.eq(i).removeClass('darkened');
    } else {
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#99daf0';
      darkened.eq(i).addClass('darkened');
    }

    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  function jetPosition(y) {
    var angle = Math.asin((centerY - y) / radius);
    var currentX = centerX + radius * (Math.cos(angle) - 1);

    var firstPointRad = Math.asin((centerY - firstPoint) / radius);

    // if (toUp) {   // Самолетик вверх-вниз
    var jetAngle = Math.acos((centerY - y) / radius);
    // } else {
    //  var jetAngle = Math.acos((centerY - y) / radius) + Math.PI;
    // }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, -angle, -firstPointRad, true);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.stroke();

    draw(y);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(currentX + radius, y)
    ctx.rotate(jetAngle - 1.6);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.drawImage(jet, -106, -80, 212, 160);
    ctx.restore();
  }

  function jetPositionLine(y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(tabletOffset, firstPoint);
    ctx.lineTo(tabletOffset, y);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.stroke();

    draw(y);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.drawImage(jet, tabletOffset - 106, y - 80, 212, 160);
    ctx.restore();
  }

  function onScroll() {
    requestAnimationFrame(scrollCanvas);
  };

  function scrollCanvas() {
    var prevScroll = scrolled;
    scrolled = window.pageYOffset;

    toUp = prevScroll < scrolled;
    var positionY = scrolled + jetOnScroll;
    if (positionY >= firstPoint) {
      if (positionY <= lastPoint) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasClearWidth, canvasHeight);

        if (mediaTablet) {
          jetPositionLine(positionY);
        } else {
          jetPosition(positionY);
        }
      } else {
        $('.history__item').eq(lastIndex).removeClass('darkened');
      }
    }
    if (!mediaMobile && !mediaTablet) {
      parallaxScroll();
    }
  }
```

Comment: What are you displaying in the canvas apart from images? If just images, you can just use a simple html `<img>` tag and change the `src` from the js